# Need VBA script to extend Excel table every week

Tags: vba, excel, automation

The problem is as follows: I have several tables in Excel with given number of raws and dynamic number of columns (each week a new column should be added, currently I'm doing it manually). I want to automate it and create a script that will extend every raw range to the next column (namely the range from A2 to C2 should become from A2 to D2), and so on (such that running script N times will result in extending a table to N columns further). By "extending" I mean extending formulas, since each cell in my tables contains any formula. Is there any way to do it via VBA?

I can't just record the corresponding macro because I have now idea how to specify that I don't want to link it with any specific range, but instead always extend just to one column right.

Any help and examples will be very appreciative.

Comment: If these are "real tables", the ListObject will provide the # of columns.  So just add one column to each ListObject, then copy from the next to last to the last column.  If these are not "real tables", there are other ways to locate the table on a worksheet, depending on your data.

Comment: I agree with @RonRosenfeld that using tables/listobjects is worth exploring in your scenario, here's a nice introduction. https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

Answer (score 1):

You dont need VBA to do this. Use dynamic defined names and reference them in your formulas. For example, if you add a named range and add this in the refersTo dialog

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A),COUNTA($1:$1)
```

your range will automatically expand from cell A1 (as long as there are no blank cells in column A or Row 1). You can then use that named range in your formulae.

More here http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html